# #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Having a problem opening any of my databases in phpMyadmin
I tried deleting a lot of old, irrelevant databases and may have in the process
deleted something I shouldn't have and was wondering what I could do to resolve the error

> #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist

Comment: Re-Create/Restore the table or even the database you deleted by mistake.

Comment: Solved - Upgraded phpMyAdmin as given here - https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Solved - Upgraded phpMyAdmin as given here - https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All the phpMyAdmin tables are defined in the SQL dump that comes with the package in [sql/create_tables.sql](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql). You can import that file in it's entirety (will also re-create any other tables you might have dropped) or just create the missing table by running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
  `schema_sql` text,
  `data_sql` longtext,
  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
  COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Switch to the phpmyadmin database. You can then use the "SQL" tab to execute this query directly on the database.

Comment: Works for me after updating phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks!

Comment: Not working!!!!! When I import create_tables.sql or run this query it says #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha That error indicates a corrupted database altogether and needs a [different approach](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%201932%20Table%20doesn%27t%20exist%20in%20engine&rct=j).

Comment: @Oldskool: Cannot select phpmyadmin database. Getting `#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine`

Comment: Gives error as ``#1813 - Tablespace for table '`phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.``

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after installed XAMPP. I did the following:

> 1. In `/opt/lampp/bin1` use `./mysql_upgrade -u root` with option `-p` if you use a password.
> 2. In `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/phpmyadmin` `rm` all `*.ibd` files.
> 3. Import [create_tables.sql](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql) in phpMyAdmin GUI or run it in console.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem.

I created **pma__** tables in my project db by clicking something in operations tab of that db.

Then I deleted my db, created new with the same name and got "table does not exist" problem.

Fixed it by executing modified **sql/create_table.sql** on my db. Had to delete **phpmyadmin** db creation and use from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I switched from `mysql` to `maraidb`. The solution was to do the following, run the create tables script from the console.

Get to the terminal

```
   $ mysql -uroot -padmin
```

Then import the create `phpmyadmin` db and tables script, I got it from Oldskool's answer above. (READ it before running it)

```
 MariaDB [(none)]> source create_tables_phpmyadmin.sql;
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 Database changed
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
 ...
```

In case of `exists` error you may clear your previous `phpmyadmin` db that you had tried adding.