# Error restoring all databases in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.3

I needed PHP 5.6 because of Laravel 5.3, so I backed up my `htdocs` directory and backed up `C:\xampp\mysql\data` directory and uninstalled xammp then installed a new version. After restoring these two directories, I can still see all my Databases in phpmyadmin but I can't open any of them, keep getting this error:

```
phpmyadmin.pma_tracking' doesn't exist
```

Apparently I've tried almost all suggestions I've come accross online and none is working for me.
Can Someone help please. Been on this for some hours now.

I also tried to remove this line in `config.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
```

But it still did not help.

Comment: This post will probably helps: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Actually came across that post, but running the SQL command returns error `No database selected` meanwhile I can't select any of my databases because of this `pma_tracking error`

Comment: Removing the $cfg line should have made a difference, but instead try removing (or commenting out) the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']`, logout from phpMyAdmin and close your browser, then try again.