# PhpMyAdmin - gives '#1146 - Table 'dancedat_aas.pma__tracking' doesn't exist' error

Tags: phpmyadmin

Have checked out other questions/answers such as [#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist) but to no avail.

I upgraded my MAMP (latest 4.0.6) on Mac (latest El Capitan) and now cannot get phpMyadmin to work at all from fresh install!
Keeps coming up with above error whenever I try and select a DB or create a new one or browse an existing db/table.

I believe the table mentioned does exist - possibly is it permissions? - I am logged in as root.

Just going around in circles for days now...

In desparation I installed SQLBuddy and can see the tables ok so it is something to do with phpMyAdmin I believe. I have checked and rechecked config.inc.php as per many answers but none of them seem to totally lock you out of the DB so you cannot even run a SQL query through phpMyAdmin.
(So I cannot run the create tables sql script suggested elsewhere.)

Thanks

Comment: Does that specified table exist?

Comment: It did. I have attempted to delete all tables and create a new empty database with sqlbuddy but I still cannot access any details of (no) tables through - same symptoms.