# Can't export database from phpmyadmin(error: #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When I'm trying to export the database, Select database, Select table or edit database details there is an error in phpmyadmin as follows,

> #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist

[image]

This error occurs for all databases which I have created before as well. I'm currently using WAMP server 64bit and using Windows machine.

PS: I have already referred [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist) for this issue and didn't find a solution to this problem.

I can't even refresh phpmyadmin. There is a message as follows when I'm refreshing the site,

```
Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT `comment`
            FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info`
            WHERE db_name     = 'busresavation'
                AND table_name  = ''
                AND column_name = '(db_comment)'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reconfigure phpMyAdmin using this command as it works many a times after reconfiguration.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Are all past databases deleting when reconfiguration process?

Comment: It won't delete any database. You are reconfiguring phpMyAdmin and it has nothing to do with MySQL database

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing.  The file missing is one just for phpMyAdmin, and not one of your tables, so it shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake Did you found any solution?

Comment: It worked . This is the answer what im looking for. Thnks

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem recently with not being able to refresh phpMyAdmin and getting errors and warnings left and right. I tried many solutions posted online but at the end, I transferred to XAMPP and now everything works great. Still, don't know what was the problem.